# Python Gtk+3 Window.present not work with GNOME Builder

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

environment:

- Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3
- GNOME Builder 3.26.3

The GNOME Builder generated project use GtkTemplate to interpret ui, But I change it to use Gtk.Builder to interpret. After modifying, it does not work.
And I can not see any error message.

```
class Application(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(application_id='org.gnome.Ee',
                         flags = Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE)
    def do_startup(self):
        print('do_startup')
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)
        builder = Gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_resource("/org/gnome/Ee/window.ui")
        print(builder)
        self.builder = builder
    def do_activate(self):
        print("do_activate")
        win = self.props.active_window
        if not win:
            win = self.builder.get_object("EeWindow")
            print(win)
        win.present() # not work, can not see the window
```

I have upload the demo code to Github: https://github.com/Honghe/gnome_builder_demo

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your git history doesn't make it obvious what are the modifications you have done. Have you tried replacing `win.present()` by `win.show_all()`?

Comment: @liberforce Sorry, I have re-uploaded the project with modification history. You can check now. Thanks!  `win.show_all()` does not work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application does not know about the window so it exits immediately. You need to call `win.set_application(self)` after you created an instance of the window.

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question, Why does this demo(https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builder.html ) work?

Comment: It does not explicitly create a `Gtk.Application` and therefore calls `Gtk.main()` instead of `Application.run()`.